# GTA: Online Bikers DLC

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Where can you check all the contents of the newly released Bikers DLC for GTA: Online?
The only thing I found was the trailer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patch notes can be found on Rockstar's website. Specific patch notes for the bikers patch can be found [here](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/228742727-GTAV-Title-Update-1-36-Notes-PS4-Xbox-One-PC-).